# WPF Binding ContextMenu MenuItem's ItemsSource

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, contextmenu, menuitem

I'm trying to bind a single MenuItem's ItemsSource to a `ReadOnlyCollection<string>`located in the ViewModel. I've read that the ContextMenu is not under the main Visual tree so i can't bind it directly, but any method i try doesn't work. I have the code snippet please let me know what am i doing wrong.

```
<Window>
…
<DockPanel>
  <!-- Task bar Icon -->
  <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="AppNotifyIcon"
       DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
       ToolTipText="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=Strings.MainTitle}">
      <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                <MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=Strings.NotifyIconOpen}" Click="MenuItem_Open_Click"/>
                <MenuItem Header="Technologies" ItemsSource="{Binding to the ReadOnlyCollection of string in ViewModel}">
                   <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                       <Style>
                          <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding <!--Command in ViewModel-->, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=Window}}"/>
                          <Setter Property="MenuItem.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/> <!—Binding to the menuItem Header item -->
                       </Style>
                   </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
               </MenuItem>
               <MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=Strings.NotifyIconExit}" Click="MenuItem_Exit_Click"/>
          </ContextMenu>
      </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
   </tb:TaskbarIcon>
…
</DockPanel>
```

I am trying to bind the second MenuItem's ItemsSource and inside it's ItemContainerStyle i want to bind the command and the commandParameter.
**Update: ** i'm using hardcodet's TaskbarIcon for wpf, if it matters.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to provide a `RelativeSource` in your Binding?

Comment: I've tried with the window as the relativeSource and it didn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I have found the problem thanks to Ilan's suggestion in the comments of using snoop utility.
I saw that in the visual tree, the ContextMenu didn't have its PlacementTarget to point to its parent, the TaskbarIcon (Weird..), but it had an Attached Property called TaskbarIcon.ParentTaskbarIcon from the TaskbarIcon, so i binded the ContextMenu's DataContext to the TaskbarIcon.ParentTaskbarIcon.Tag and that fixed it all.

```
<Window>
...
<DockPanel>
            <!-- Task bar Icon -->
            <tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="AppNotifyIcon"
                        IconSource="pack://application:,,,/Icons/HwServerIcon.ico"
                        Tag="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                        ToolTipText="{Binding Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"><!--{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=Strings.MainTitle}-->
                <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=(tb:TaskbarIcon.ParentTaskbarIcon).Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=Strings.NotifyIconOpen}" Click="MenuItem_Open_Click"/>
                        <MenuItem Header="Technologies" ItemsSource="{Binding TechnologiesNames}">
                            <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                                <Style>
                                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding DataContext.OpenTechnology, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}}"/>
                                    <Setter Property="MenuItem.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
                                </Style>
                            </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        </MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=Strings.NotifyIconExit}" Click="MenuItem_Exit_Click"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
            </tb:TaskbarIcon>
```

So, the TaskbarIcon's Tag is pointing the Window's DataContext and the ContextMenu's DataContext is pointing the Taskbar's attached property ParentTaskbarIcon.Tag and from now every binding is performed like it was under the window in the visual tree.

Comment: fine, you can change the (tb:TaskbarIcon.ParentTaskbarIcon).Tag to PlacementTarget.Tag.

Comment: @Ilan, that was the problem in the first place. The PlacementTarget was empty, i saw it on snoop. That's why it didn't work.

Comment: the problem wasn't on it. your context menu tried to get the data context of a TaskbarIcon user control, it called its data context and tried to get the ItemsSource from there, that's all.

Comment: Yes you right, originally i tried to take the PlacementTarget.DataContext but later i've replaced the DataContext to Tag and even then it didn't work. I've tried it again now just to make sure, for somehow the ContextMenu's PlacementTarget is empty. Only the attached property has the value of the TaskbarIcon.

Answer (score 1):

Try check this out:
 1. XAML Code:

```
        <DataGrid x:Name="SelectDataGrid" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding Persons}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" CellEditEnding="SelectDataGrid_OnCellEditEnding"
              VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Loaded="SelectDataGrid_OnLoaded">
        <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
            <ContextMenu>
                <MenuItem Header="Technologies" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuItems}">
                    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
                            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Command}"/>
                            <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Content}"/>
                            <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ContextMenu}}, Path=DataContext}"/>
                        </Style>
                    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                </MenuItem>
            </ContextMenu>
        </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Button Command="{Binding HelloCommand}"></Button>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn></DataGrid>
```

2. DataContext of the context menu is the same as datagrid and window.
 3. Inside the DataContext put the next code:

```
    private void Init()
    {
        MenuItems = new ObservableCollection<MenuItemObject>(new List<MenuItemObject>
        {
            new MenuItemObject {Command = new RelayCommand<object>(Execute), Content = "A"},
            new MenuItemObject {Command = new RelayCommand<object>(Execute), Content = "B"},
            new MenuItemObject {Command = new RelayCommand<object>(Execute), Content = "C"},
            new MenuItemObject {Command = new RelayCommand<object>(Execute), Content = "D"},
        });
    }

    public ObservableCollection<MenuItemObject> MenuItems { get; set; }

    private void Execute(object o)
    {

    }
```

4. MenuItemsObject model code:

```
public class MenuItemObject:BaseObservableObject
{
    private ICommand _command;
    private string _content;

    public ICommand Command
    {
        get { return _command; }
        set
        {
            _command = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public string Content
    {
        get { return _content; }
        set
        {
            _content = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

5. MVVM parts implementation:

```
    public class BaseObservableObject : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged<T>(Expression<Func<T>> raiser)
    {
        var propName = ((MemberExpression)raiser.Body).Member.Name;
        OnPropertyChanged(propName);
    }

    protected bool Set<T>(ref T field, T value, [CallerMemberName] string name = null)
    {
        if (!EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(field, value))
        {
            field = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(name);
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

public class RelayCommand<T> : ICommand
{
    readonly Action<T> _execute;
    readonly Func<T, bool> _canExecute;

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    public RelayCommand(Action<T> execute, Func<T, bool> canExecute = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
    }

    public void RefreshCommand()
    {
        var cec = CanExecuteChanged;
        if (cec != null)
            cec(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        if (_canExecute == null) return true;
        return _canExecute((T)parameter);
    }

    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        _execute((T)parameter);
    }
}

public class RelayCommand : RelayCommand<object>
{
    public RelayCommand(Action execute, Func<bool> canExecute = null)
        : base(_ => execute(),
            _ => canExecute == null || canExecute())
    {

    }
}
```

6. Call to Init method to generate toy menu item's collection DataContext.
7. An Execute is the method called when some menu item is pressed.

That is all. I'will be glad to help if there will be problems with the code.
Regards,

Comment: Hi Ilan, thanks for the answer, but that doesn't serves my needs. I am looking to bind to a collection of strings in the ViewModel and the problem is that the ContextMenu is not located under the DataGrid (or in my case the TaskbarIcon) in the visual tree hirarchy.  So the ContextMenu's DataContext is not taken from the datagrid (or TaskBarIcon)  nor the window.

Comment: @MaorB Hi, what viewmodel you want to be binded to? The viewmodel of the solution is binded to the window viewmodel. Try to be more specific, where is  that viewmodel you want to be binded to?

Comment: Sorry, The ViewModel I want to bind to is the window's ViewModel, in it I have a `ReadOnlyCollection<string>` that is called TechnologyList for example and i want that the MenuItem's ItemSource will be bound to it. thanks.

Comment: @MaorB Are your TaskbarIcon or DockPanel a part of datatemplate. Can you publish whole xaml code where those control are part of (they are part of listboxitem template or something)?

Comment: No Ilan, My DockPanel is a direct child of the Window. It goes Window -> DockPanel -> TaskbarIcon.

Answer (score 0):

For a context menu in a ListBox I add my DataContext to the parent control's tag, and find it in a relative source binding to the placement target.  There are many questions on SO regarding this though, and some of those may address more specific instances.

```
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ItemList}"
         SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"
         Tag="{Binding}">
                <ListBox.ContextMenu>
                    <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                        <MenuItem Header="Delete" 
                                  Command="{Binding Path=DeleteCommand}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </ListBox.ContextMenu>
            </ListBox>
```

So for your example specifically:

```
<tb:TaskbarIcon x:Name="AppNotifyIcon"
                DataContext="{Binding Path=DataContext, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}"
                ToolTipText="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=Strings.MainTitle}"
                Tag="{Binding}">
    <tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
        <ContextMenu DataContext="{Binding Path=PlacementTarget.Tag, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
            <MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=Strings.NotifyIconOpen}" Click="MenuItem_Open_Click"/>
            <MenuItem Header="Technologies" ItemsSource="{Binding TechnologyList}">
               <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
                   <Style>
                      <Setter Property="MenuItem.Command" Value="{Binding VmCommand}"/>
                      <Setter Property="MenuItem.CommandParameter" Value="{Binding}"/>
                   </Style>
               </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
           </MenuItem>
           <MenuItem Header="{Binding Source={StaticResource LocalizedStrings}, Path=Strings.NotifyIconExit}" Click="MenuItem_Exit_Click"/>
      </ContextMenu>
  </tb:TaskbarIcon.ContextMenu>
```

Of course your bindings will probably vary, but from here you should at least have the DataContext set, and go from there.

Comment: Thank you Matthew for the answer. I've tried your answer but it still doesn't work. I get a null DataContext. To verify it instead of "Technologies" in the MenuItem's Header i placed a binding to the DataContext value to see if i get the DataContext's value: `Header="{Binding}"` and i don't see anything. So I can't get to the part of binding to the ViewModel's List because the binding to the ViewModel doesn't work.

Comment: @MaorB try snoop (https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/), and look where your datacontext is broken. there are number of data binding way to use...

Comment: @Ilan Thank you for the suggestion of using snoop. I found the problem using this tool, I'll post the solution.

Comment: Indeed, snoop is a great tool.  Another one very similar, but for me has been more reliable is Christian Moser's WPF Inspector.